# property of the exterior derivative $d \circ d=$ for a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

One of the properties of the exterior derivative is that $d\circ d=0$. We're trying to prove this for the case $f\in\mathcal C^\infty (U)$ on an open set $U\subset \mathbb R^n $.
The prove starts with the uniqueness of the exterior derivative using the properties:

1. $d$ is $\mathbb R$-linear
2. $d\circ d=0$
3. If $f$ is in $\mathcal C^\infty(U)$, $df$ is the differential of $f$.
4. $d(\omega\wedge\eta)=d\omega\wedge \eta+(-1^k) \omega \wedge d\eta$

Now to the existence of $d$:

What I'm interested in is the proof of $d\circ d=0$. Let $f\in\mathcal C^\infty (U)$.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
ddf &=& d(\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i) \\ &=&
\sum_{i=0}^n d(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}) \cdot  dx_i+ \sum_{i=0}^n (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}) d(dx_i)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The argument for the left part of the sum is the lemma of schwartz and the alternating property and i got the soultion.The other part is the problem.
Now $d(dx_i)$ is the exterior derivative of a 1-form, as were trying to prove $d\circ d=0$ it is not clear to me on how to deduce that this part of the sums is $0$.

Comment: I'm confused. You've listed this property as one of the known properties. For existence, shouldn't you start with a definition, like $d\big(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\,dx_i\big)=\sum_{i=1}^n da_i\wedge dx_i$? Ultimately, to do what you were trying to do will require using equality of mixed partials.

Comment: My professor showed the formula $dw =\dots = \sum_{i=1}^n df dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, by using the properties of $d$.He then proceeded to prove the existence of the function by using this implicit defintion of $d$. He started with $d$ of a 0-form.Now using this defintion we get two sums.The one sum $\sum_{i=0}^n (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}) d(dx_i)$ i don't know how to handle, because we're still in the process of showing $d\circ d=0$ for 0-forms and had'nt had a word of n-forms yet. I'm sorry if my question isn't clear enough, and 'm not sure how to apply mixed partials to 1-forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your list of properties you should add locality, i.e. if 2 forms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ coincide on an open set $U$, then $d\alpha=d\beta$ on $U$.

More generally, denoting by $M$ a given manifold, if $\omega\in\Omega^{n}(M)$ is locally represented by $w=w_{i_1\dots i_n}dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_n}$, then, denoting by $d'$ an operator that satisfies all properties 1-4 above, by using 4)

$$d'w=(d'w_{i_1\dots i_n})dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_n}+
w_{i_1\dots i_n}d'(dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_n});
 $$
using 3) we arrive at $ d'w_{i_1\dots i_n}=dw_{i_1\dots i_n}$ and $d'x_{i_l}=dx_{i_l}$.
Using 3) and 4) we have then $d'(dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_n})=0$, as $d'x_{i_l}=dx_{i_l}$ for all $l=1,\dots, n$.

So $d'$ is the uniquely defined operator $d$, where $d$ is the operator

$$dw=\frac{\partial w_{i_1\dots i_n}}{\partial x_k}dx_k\wedge dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_n}.$$

Property 2) is satisfied as

$$ d(dw)=\frac{\partial^2 w_{i_1\dots i_n}}{\partial x_k\partial x_r}dx_r\wedge dx_k\wedge dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_n}=0,$$

as we sum over all $r,k=1,\dots, n$, with $dx_r\wedge dx_k=-dx_k\wedge dx_r$.